# Unix-CSV Formatting

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to convert the below format from A to B, where you can see the first two columns are interchanged in the final format together with their data intact and piped between them and the tricky part is the last one where date format is changed from  2016-09-06 08:49:00 to "09/06/2016 08:49:00 AM". I am using bash shell and need a script to do the same.

A:

```
Display Name,SAM Account Name,Distinguished Name,Last Logon Time Stamp
Yolanda Perez,yperez1,"CN=Yolanda Perez,OU=Users,OU=PR - Miami SPCG,OU=PR - Puerto Rico,OU=Puerto Rico,OU=Caribbean - Unified,DC=intl,DC=bns",2016-09-06 08:49:00
```

B:

```
"SAM Account Name"|"Display Name"|"Distinguished Name"|"Last Logon Time Stamp"
"yperez1"|"Yolanda Perez,CN=Yolanda Perez"|"OU=Users,OU=PR - Miami SPCG,OU=PR - Puerto Rico,OU=Puerto Rico,OU=Caribbean - Unified,DC=intl,DC=bns"|"09/06/2016 08:49:00 AM"
```

Comment: Value of the "display name" field seems to be different in B.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the value is something like below in B

Comment: "SAM Account Name"|"Display Name"|"Distinguished Name"|"Last Logon Time Stamp"
"yperez1"|"Yolanda Perez"|"CN=Yolanda Perez,OU=Users,OU=PR - Miami SPCG,OU=PR - Puerto Rico,OU=Puerto Rico,OU=Caribbean - Unified,DC=intl,DC=bns"|"09/06/2016 08:49:00 AM"

Comment: Sorry, I meant Barun, can you please advise arun..

Comment: ./RealLastLogon-20160908.csv: line 1: Display: command not found
./RealLastLogon-20160908.csv: line 2: Yolanda: command not found
Gives abover error with

Comment: eval "column=$($input | cut -d"|" -f$counter)" eval "text=$($input | cut -d"|" -f$counter | grep '"')" if [[ "$column" = "$text" && -n "$column" ]] if [[ "$result" = "" ]] result="""${column}""" result="${result}|""${column}""" if [[ -n "$column" ]] if [[ "$result" = "" ]] result="${column}" result="${result}|${column}" $result | sed 's/""/"/g' > .txt –

Answer (score 1):

I think that trying to do it purely in bash would be fairly tricky.

There is a program `csvfix` that should do most of the work for you: http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/

Comment: Thanks, but we cant use the same, as the need is to write a bash, have already got some idea from the below code, but stuck up with some error

Comment: due to line constraints cant add all the code, but this was from the forum as well eval "column=$($input | cut -d"|" -f$counter)"
eval "text=$($input | cut -d"|" -f$counter | grep '"')"
if [[ "$column" = "$text" && -n "$column" ]]
  
        if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
       
            result="""${column}"""
      
            result="${result}|""${column}"""
    

        if [[ -n "$column" ]]
     
            if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
      
                result="${column}"
        
               result="${result}|${column}"
   
   $result | sed 's/""/"/g' > .txt

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650812/147021) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122020/147021).

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -vOFS=, '{
    if (NR == 1) {
        print "\""$2"\"" "|" "\""$1"\"" "|" "\"" $3 "\"" "|" "\""$4"\""
    } else {
        cmd ="date \"+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" -d \""$4"\""
        cmd | getline var
        close(cmd)
        print "\""$2"\"" "|" "\""$1"\"" "|"$3"|" "\""var"\""
    }
}' data.csv
```

Here, `data.csv` is the input file (`A` in your example). Execute the above script (named `csv2pipe.sh`) as:
`bash csv2pipe.sh`. The output is shown below.

```
"SAM Account Name"|"Display Name"|"Distinguished Name"|"Last Logon Time Stamp"
"yperez1"|"Yolanda Perez"|"CN=Yolanda Perez,OU=Users,OU=PR - Miami SPCG,OU=PR - Puerto Rico,OU=Puerto Rico,OU=Caribbean - Unified,DC=intl,DC=bns"|"09/06/2016 08:49:00 AM"
```

Comment: Hi arun, seems like there is some Syntax issue ./csv2pipe.sh, tried both./ bash csv2pipe.sh and ./csv2pipe.sh, had the following in console below. Modified the double quotes but still did not seem to work
awk: syntax error near line 6
awk: illegal statement near line 6
awk: syntax error near line 10
awk: bailing out near line 10

Comment: Hi Arun, tried the same with nawk, but when executed there is no Output, any idea on the same, kindly advise?

Comment: The pattern matching used here is supported by GNU version of `awk`; not sure about other versions. Also, you should execute the script as `bash ./csv2pipe.sh` not `./bash csv2pipe.sh` -- but I think you figured that out. You can also refer to the posts linked in my answer for alternative approaches. Apart from these, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Arun, in the above when date logic is processed, where do we check if the time is AM or PM, how is this being done when the date is converted. I am using the Solaris version of the bash shell, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: The AM/PM is determined (using the `%p` argument) based on the input time assuming that it is in 24-hour format.

Comment: Executing just this with a date passed to it as Param does not seems to work date \"+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" . Also , in my third column I do have comma inside the data, if I give IFS =, then it treats the third column data as individual columns as it encounters data, how do i treat it as one column, still keeping the data intact with comma 
while IFS=',' read -r f2 f1 f3 f4
do
  echo "$f1|$f2|$f3|$f4"

Comment: Hi Arun/Stephen, made the date command work, however i am still not able to format the first three columns, where the below is shown if the shell is executed, any help is much appreciated

Comment: "Name,SAM"|"Display"|"Account"|"Name,Distinguished"
"Perez,yperez1,"CN=Yolanda"|"Yolanda"|"Perez,OU=Users,OU=PR"|"-"
"-"|"SCANNER224,SCANNER224,"CN=SCANNER224,OU=Users,OU=PR"|"Miami"|"SPCG,OU=PR"

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -alne '
  print $.==1? "\"".join("\"|\"", $F[1], $F[0], @F[2..$#F])."\""
  : join("|", "\"".$F[1]."\"", "\"".join(",", $F[0], substr($F[2],1))."\"", "\"".join(",", @F[3..9]), Time::Piece->strptime($F[10], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")->strftime("\"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\""))
' file.csv
"SAM Account Name"|"Display Name"|"Distinguished Name"|"Last Logon Time Stamp"
"yperez1"|"Yolanda Perez,CN=Yolanda Perez"|"OU=Users,OU=PR - Miami SPCG,OU=PR - Puerto Rico,OU=Puerto Rico,OU=Caribbean - Unified,DC=intl,DC=bns"|"09/06/2016 08:49:00 AM"
```

Comment: String found where operator expected at ./Parse.pl line 4, near ": join("|", "\"".$F[1]."\"", "\"".join(",", $F[0], ($F[2],1))."\"", "\"".join(",", @F[3..9]), Time::Piece->($F[10], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")->("\"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\""))'"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 2)
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
found where operator expected at ./Parse.pl line 4, near "file"
        (Missing operator before file?)
syntax error at ./Parse.pl line 4, near ": join("|", "\"".$F[1]."\"", "\"".join(",", 
Execution of ./Parse.pl aborted due to compilation errors.